# Send two variables to php through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

An easy one I can't find the answer to

Would this be the right way to do it?

Jquery/Javascript

```
var result = result.text;
var users = localStorage.getItem('user');

$.ajax({
       url:'******',
       method: 'POST',
       data: {user: users, serial: result},
       dataType: "text",
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function(data){
```

PHP- :

```
$u1 = ($_POST['user']);
$duid = ($_POST['serial']);
```

Comment: Well it look OK, so what is the probelm?

Comment: So the php will extract each variable okay?

Comment: I would loose the `contentType: "application/json",` line

Comment: Hint: You can find out the answer if you try it#

Comment: a simple `var_dump($_POST);` in your target page will show you it works fine.